# Pandas Improving Efficiency

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with approximately 3 million rows.
I want to partially aggregate the last column in seperate spots based on another variable.

My solution was to separate the dataframe rows into a list of new dataframes based on that variable, aggregate the dataframes, and then join them again into a single dataframe. The problem is that after a few 10s of thousands of rows, I get a memory error. What methods can I use to improve the efficiency of my function to prevent these memory errors?

An example of my code is below

```
test = pd.DataFrame({"unneeded_var": [6,6,6,4,2,6,9,2,3,3,1,4,1,5,9],
                     "year": [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3], 
                     "month" : [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4],
                     "day" : [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5], 
                     "day_count" : [7,4,3,2,1,5,4,2,3,2,5,3,2,1,3]})
test = test[["year", "month", "day", "day_count"]]

def agg_multiple(df, labels, aggvar, repl=None):
    if(repl is None): repl = aggvar
    conds = df.duplicated(labels).tolist() #returns boolean list of false for a unique (year,month) then true until next unique pair
    groups = []
    start = 0
    for i in range(len(conds)): #When false, split previous to new df, aggregate count 
        bul = conds[i]
        if(i == len(conds) - 1): i +=1 #no false marking end of last group, special case
        if not bul and i > 0 or bul and i == len(conds): 
            sample = df.iloc[start:i , :]
            start = i
            sample = sample.groupby(labels, as_index=False).agg({aggvar:sum}).rename(columns={aggvar : repl})
            groups.append(sample)
    df = pd.concat(groups).reset_index(drop=True) #combine aggregated dfs into new df
    return df



test = agg_multiple(test, ["year", "month"], "day_count", repl="month_count")
```

I suppose that I could potentially apply the function to small samples of the dataframe, to prevent a memory error and then combine those, but I'd rather improve the computation time of my function.

Comment: Use groupby is even better, but if you want a list of subdataframes based on a column, you can just do `[df.loc[df[col]==value] for value in set(df[col])]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *almost* always `pandas` methods that are pretty optimized for tasks that will vastly outperform iteration through the dataframe. If I understand correctly, in your case, the following will return the same exact output as your function:

```
test2 = (test.groupby(['year', 'month'])
         .day_count.sum()
         .to_frame('month_count')
         .reset_index())

>>> test2
   year  month  month_count
0     0      0           16
1     1      1           10
2     2      2            7
3     2      3            5
4     3      3            5
5     3      4            4
```

To check that it's the same:

```
# Your original function:
test = agg_multiple(test, ["year", "month"], "day_count", repl="month_count")

>>> test == test2
   year  month  month_count
0  True   True         True
1  True   True         True
2  True   True         True
3  True   True         True
4  True   True         True
5  True   True         True
```

Comment: Glad to help! `Happy coding!`

Answer (score 3):

This function does the same, and is 10 times faster.

```
test.groupby(["year", "month"], as_index=False).agg({"day_count":sum}).rename(columns={"day_count":"month_count"})
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm surprised that works. I wrote basically the same code for my samples but in my head aggregate would reduce to 1 row in the end.

Comment: Yes, aggregate would reduce it to one row per group. In this case, since both year and month are used in groupby, one row would be returned for each pair of year and month.